# Does ArangoDB Foxx support auto scaling of microservices?

Tags: microservices, arangodb, foxx

Does ArangoDB Foxx support auto scaling of microservices? Can I configure Foxx to increase deployed instances of a specific microservice?

Comment: foxx is bound to DB, therefore it's already "scaled up". In practice foxx runs on some controller type node which comes in ratio/batch to db and other node types. The real question is if mesos will distinguish which node needs scaling. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51144660/auto-scaling-resources-for-foxx-arangodb-on-mesos