# Auto scaling resources for foxx/arangodb on mesos

Tags: arangodb, mesos, foxx

Is it possible to separately autoscale foxx and arangodb independently of each other in liu of trying to strike balance, and sure enough autoscale right amount of ram/storage/cpu? Simply if it's a good idea to try and autoscale deployment is answer good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You are not very specific about what you mean by saying "scaling ArangoDB".

In general, you can add more DB server nodes (primaries) independent of the number of coordinator nodes, if that is what you're asking. Foxx is executed on coordinators in a cluster. Your data is stored on DB servers. The cluster configuration is managed by agent nodes. An agency count of 3 is recommended (it must always be an odd number).

Comment: I mean autoscaling of resources for either foxx or arangodb

Answer (score 0):

yes you can scale the different roles of an ArangoDB cluster independently to serve different use cases best (Agents, Coordinators, DBservers).

If you are using Foxx a lot, then you can increase the number of coordinator instances where the Foxx services live. You should be able to do this for Mesos by accessing the ArangoDB WebUI -> Nodes and in the upper right corner you have a button for Coordinators and one for DBservers. Just click on the "+" sign and a new coordinator will get started.

Comment: im asking about autoscaling